# How to handle session? When do we create a session id

Tags: android

Hi all im facing a problem, and i need suggestion from the experts out here.
There is Shopping  cart module in my project that uses webservice .The workflow is

1. Create session Id.( I have an xml input which returns me a long string as session id)
2. Add Product to cart ( WHere i use the above session id  and the product unique code as xm input)
3. Get cart ( Here the input parameter in the xml is the sessionid.Means i will get a list product in that session)
4. Delete from cart( Here the xml parameters are session id and product unique code)

What i have done is while loading the splash screen i have written code to generate the session id and i keep it in  the first location of a list for later use.

```
    CartService cartService=new CartServiceImpl();
    SterviceResponse ob = cartService.createPartnerSession();
    Session session = new Session();
    session.setSessionId(ob.getStringValue());
```

Session.getSessionId() will return me the session id
The program works fine if there is no internet problem,But if i switch off wifi in between the program will crash.Now i will have to restart the app to start a new session.Also i want to expire the session if the phone is idle for a particular period of time.

What is the best way to store and handle session id in side the program?

Comment: Unfortuntly yes.I had to deal with sessions in my project

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.
1. If you are using JSP then after the page is displayed you can use session.invalidate(). Some thing like this in your jsp-

```
<%  
    session.invalidate();  
%>  
<h2>Session Destroyed successfully.. </h2>
```

1. You can set session time out in your web.xml file

> ```
> <session-config>
> <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
> </session-config>
> ```